# Struct to complex JSON parsing in golang

Tags: json, parsing, go

I have a valid JSON, which I don't know how to parse in json.Unmarshal (golang):

```
{
   "method": "notice",
   "params": [0, [{
           "previous": "12345",
           "timestamp": "2017-12-12T05:49:09",
           "witness": "12345",
           "transaction_merkle_root": "ffff",
           "extensions": [],
           "witness_signature": "12345"
   }]]
}
```

All I can do is:

```
type MyJSON struct {
    Method string        `json:"method"`
    Params []interface{} `json:"params"`
}
```

I will be really thankful if somebody help me to write correct MyJSON type to parse all other fields through golang's json.Unmarshal. It's way too complex to me :(

Answer (score 3):

I assume that `params` depends on the `method`.  If so, start by decoding the top-level to a struct with the method name and a [json.RawMessage](https://godoc.org/encoding/json#RawMessage) to collect the parameters as JSON text.

```
var call struct {
    Method string
    Params json.RawMessage
}
if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &call); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Declare variables for each parameter. This code will depend on the method.

```
    var param0 int
    var param1 []struct {
        Previous                string
        Timestamp               string
        Witness                 string
        Transaction_merkle_root string
        Extensions              []interface{}
        Witness_signature       string
    }
```

Create a parameter list using pointers to those variables.

```
    params := []interface{}{&param0, &param1}
```

Now unmarshal the JSON to params. This will set the variables param0 and param1:

```
    if err := json.Unmarshal(call.Params, &params); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

Repeat for other methods.

[Here's the runnable code on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/U0mcP0gC62).

This can be simplified if you will only need to handle the "notice" method. In this case, you can decode directly to the parameters without the RawMessage step.

```
var param0 int
var param1 []struct {
    Previous                string
    Timestamp               string
    Witness                 string
    Transaction_merkle_root string
    Extensions              []interface{}
    Witness_signature       string
}
call := struct {
    Method string
    Params []interface{}
}{
    Params: []interface{}{&param0, &param1},
}

if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &call); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

[Here's runnable code for the simple case](https://play.golang.org/p/eRxeTumdCt).

Answer (score 1):

Try using [fastjson](https://github.com/valyala/fastjson). It is able to parse and query arbitrary JSON without defining additional structs and without code generation:

```
var p fastjson.Parser
v, err := p.Parse(data)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Printf("method=%s", v.GetStringBytes("method"))

// GetStringBytes accepts a path of keys to extract json value.
// Array indexes must be passed as decimal strings.
fmt.Printf("timestamp=%s", v.GetStringBytes("params", "1", "0", "timestamp"))
```